# Symfony form Event Listener for collection fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2, symfony-3.1

I use event listener for change data dynamically based on user inputs. Each time I use `PRE_SET_DATA` and `PRE_SUBMIT` events for set data and fields choices. Here is the simple example of actions from `PRE_SUBMIT`:

```
// Pre set share locations by share day
if (array_key_exists('shares', $data)) {
    foreach ($data['shares'] as $key => $share) {
        if ($share['pickUpDay'] !== null) {
            $shareType = $form->get('shares')->get($key);

            $locations = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member\Location')->getLocationsByDay($client, $data['shares'][$key]['pickUpDay']);
            $this->addLocationField($shareType, $locations);
         }
     }
 }
```

Not matter what inside `addLocationField` function, it works right.

When I do `$form->get('shares')`, its my collection field, then I need to `->get(child)` of this collection and set fields data and choices straight to this child. By when I add collection dynamically, Symfony shows error:

> Child "n" does not exist.

And this problem happens only when I try to get data of new collection that was added dynamically. So I can't get to a collection field and change choices, so I receive error that my new value is not in a choice list.

Interesting that `$data['shares']` have all data for new collection elements, but `$form->get('shares')` haven`t:

```
var_dump(count($event->getData()['shares'])) - return 1;  
var_dump(count($form->get('shares'))) - return 0;
```

Is that mean that my `PRE_SUBMIT` works before Symfony collection functionality happen?

Someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is "old" and you probably found a solution but you were in the right direction when you said :

> Is that mean that my PRE_SUBMIT works before Symfony collection functionality happen?

Your new collection is not submitted yet and it is not present in the model [see this part of the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/form/events.html#a-the-formevents-pre-submit-event)

To make what you want to, you should use [the `SUBMIT` event](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/form/events.html#b-the-formevents-submit-event)

NB : You can't add any field on `POST_SUBMIT`